# Series of inverse function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, power-series

$A(s) = \sum_{k>0}a_ks^k$ and $A(s)+A(s)^3=s$.
I want calculate $a_5$. What ways to do it most efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pretty obvious that $s\mapsto A(s)$ is odd. If you really only need $a_5$ the simplest thing is to write
$$A(s)=s+a_3s^3+a_5s^5+?s^7\ ,$$
whereby the question mark represents a full power series. Then
$$A^3(s)=s^3(1+a_3s^2+?s^4)^3$$
and therefore
$$0=A(s)+A^3(s)-s=s+a_3s^3+a_5s^5+?s^7+s^3\bigl(1+3(a_3s^2+?s^4)+?s^4\bigr)-s\ .$$
Comparing coefficients gives $a_3=-1$, $\>a_5=3$.

Answer (score 1):

$A(s) = \sum_{k>0}a_ks^k$ and $A(s)+A(s)^{3} =s$
We know (Cauchy product): $$A(s)^{2} = \sum_{n>0}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i} a_{n-i} \right) s^n$$
And
$$A(s)^{3} = \sum_{n>0}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{j=0}^{n}a_{n-j} \left( \sum_{i=0}^{j}a_{i} a_{j-i} \right) \right) s^n$$
Hence:
$$ \sum_{n>0}^{\infty}a_ns^n+\sum_{n>0}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{j=0}^{n}a_{n-j} \left( \sum_{i=0}^{j}a_{i} a_{j-i} \right) \right) s^n = s$$
For $n=0$:$$a_{0}+{a_0}^{3}=0$$
For n=1:
$$a_{1}+a_{1}.0+0=1$$
By raising the $n$ you get the $a_{n}$

Comment: I know this, but i hope there is exists more simple way.

Comment: From what you wrote, I have the feeling that $A(s)$ only contains odd power terms. This makes the calculation quite easier since we need to look at the third term.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility: the [Lagrange inversion formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem.)

$A$ is the inverse of $B(t)=t+t^3$, so
$$A(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{s^n}{n!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}\left(\frac{t}{t+t^3}\right)^n.$$

Answer (score 1):

We can elaborate on the Lagrange inversion concept.
Suppose we have $$A(s) = \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n s^n$$
and $A(s)+A(s)^3=s$ and we seek $a_n.$

Using the Cauchy Residue Theorem to prepare for Lagrange inversion we have that
$$a_n = 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|s|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{s^{n+1}} A(s) \; ds.$$

Now put $A(s)=w$ so that $w+w^3 = s$ and
$$ds = 1 + 3w^2 \;dw.$$
This yields
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{(w+w^3)^{n+1}} w \times (1+3w^2) \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{w^{n}} 
\frac{1}{(1+w^2)^{n+1}} \times (3w^2+3-2) \; dw.$$

The first component here is
$$3 \times\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{w^{n}} 
\frac{1}{(1+w^2)^{n}} \; dw
= 3\times[w^{n-1}] \frac{1}{(1+w^2)^{n}}.$$

This is zero when $n$ is even
and when $n$ is odd it yields
$$3\times (-1)^{(n-1)/2}\times {(n-1)/2+n-1\choose n-1}
= 3 (-1)^{(n-1)/2} {3/2n-3/2\choose n-1}.$$

The second component is
$$-2\times \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{w^{n}} 
\frac{1}{(1+w^2)^{n+1}} \; dw
= -2\times [w^{n-1}] \frac{1}{(1+w^2)^{n+1}}.$$

This is again zero when $n$ is even 
and when $n$ is odd it yields
$$-2\times (-1)^{(n-1)/2} {(n-1)/2+n\choose n}
= -2 (-1)^{(n-1)/2} {3/2n-1/2\choose n}.$$

Combining these two yields
$$(-1)^{(n-1)/2}
\left(3 {3/2n-3/2\choose n-1}
-2 {3/2n-1/2\choose n}\right)$$
when $n$ is odd and zero otherwise.

If desired this can be simplified to
$$(-1)^{(n-1)/2}
\left(3-2 \frac{3/2n-1/2}{n}\right)
{3/2n-3/2\choose n-1}
= (-1)^{(n-1)/2}
\frac{1}{n}{3/2n-3/2\choose n-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Here we use a somewhat simpler but equivalent variant of the *[Lagrange Inversion Formula](http://users.math.msu.edu/users/magyar/Math880/Lagrange.pdf)*. (See Theorem A.2 in *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)* by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick for the equivalence of the variants).

> **Lagrange inversion formula:**
>
> Let $B(s), A(s)\in s\mathbb{C}[s]$ be inverses: $B(A(s))=s$. If $B(s)=\frac{s}{\phi(s)}$ and 
>   $A(s)=s\phi\left(A(s)\right)$, then
>   \begin{align*}
> [s^n]A(s)=\frac{1}{n}\left[s^{n-1}\right]\left(\phi(s)\right)^n\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

The functional relation
\begin{align*}
(A(s)) + (A(s))^{3} = s
\end{align*}
can be written as $B\left(A(s)\right)=s$ with
\begin{align*}
B(s)&=s+s^3\\
&=s(1+s^2)
\end{align*}

> We can write $$\phi(s)=\frac{s}{B(s)}=\frac{1}{1+s^2}$$
>
> and obtain from (1)
>
> \begin{align*}
> [s^5]A(s)&=\frac{1}{5}\left[s^{4}\right]\left(\phi(s)\right)^5\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{5}\left[s^{4}\right]\frac{1}{(1+s^2)^{5}}\\
> &=\frac{1}{5}\left[s^{4}\right]\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{-5}{k}s^{2k}\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{5}\binom{-5}{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{(-5)(-6)}{2!}\\
> &=3
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we apply the Lagrange inversion formula (1)
- In (3) we use the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*

Answer (score 0):

Derive $A+A^3=s$ on $s$ and evaluate at $0$, giving with $A_0=0$,
$$A'+3A^2A'=1\implies A'_0=1$$
$$A''+6AA'^2+3A^2A''=0\implies A''_0=0$$
$$A'''+6A'^3+18AA'A''+3A^2A'''=0\implies A'''_0=-6$$
$$A''''+36A'^2A''+18AA''^2+24AA'A'''+3A^2A''''=0\implies A''''_0=0$$
$$A'''''+90A'A''^2+60A'^2A'''+60AA''A'''+30AA'A''''+3A^2A'''''=0\implies A'''''_0=360$$

Hence by Taylor

$$A(s)=s-\frac6{3!}s^3+\frac{360}{5!}s^5\cdots$$